# rsync create remote non-existent folder when using modules (:: syntax)

Tags: module, rsync

A similar question has been asked before but this one is different.

I am doing a rsync of a single file on remote server and destination directory does not exist. I would like the destination directory to be created if it does not exist. I am using :: syntax which uses modules and I could not find a similar case in the forums.

Here is the syntax. remote_dir2 does not exist and i want it to be created.

```
rsync -avz --password-file=<file> <source-file> remote-user@remote-server::remote_dir1/remote_dir2
```

Note: there is a module named remote-user in /etc/rsyncd.conf in the remote server and connection and everything else works, except that source file ends up in the remote_dir1 with the name of remote_dir2

Is there any solution that is different from what mentioned below ?

- I do not want to open an ssh to remote server to 'mkdir'
- I do not want to use -R, --relative because directory structure names in source and destination are very different.
- I also know that there is a trick mentioned 
  [here](http://www.schwertly.com/2013/07/forcing-rsync-to-create-a-remote-path-using-rsync-path/) but it does not work when you specify a module. There is no error or anything in the logs, apparently it gets ignored.